# Android intent-filter for .kml files not working

Tags: android, android-intent, kml

I am trying to accept ACTION_SEND for .kml files. Here's the manifest code:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"/>
  <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.kml"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEAFULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

The app builds fine, but I tried two methods to click on .kml file:
1) test.kml attachment in Google Mail app.
2) Using a file browser, and using it to click on file name, and click on Send. It only shows Google Earth and Gmail as the receiving apps.

I tried with and without the pathPattern, no change, still does not receive any intents.
I also tried testing .txt files, using mimeType="text/*" and then my app showed up for .txt files. It just seems that the mimeType for .kml is not being recognized.

Has anyone successfully received intents for .kml files to launch their app? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because you mispelled DEFAULT? (DEAFULT)

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Gmail still fails to use the installed intent-filters - it only launches Earth when an attachment is clicked, but now the file manager app can send .kml files to my app and I receive an ACTION_SEND with the .kml file Uri passed in as EXTRA_STREAM.

Comment: It's one of the things I don't like about using XML files in programming - there are ways to make typos that are hard to discover. Glad that solved it!